# Is it common for a web server to have 2 IP addresses?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm going to begin work today on setting up a new web server in our environment.  It appears to me as though the old web server has 2 IP addresses, one ending in 35 and the other ending in 36.  Is that common?  If I'm correct about this, should I set up the new one with 2 IP addresses, too?

Comment: Yes it is common. IMHO, you shouldn't even be asking.
The second addres could be used for anything (including not being used at all). You should probably spend more time understanding your old server setup before setting up the new one. If there isn't anybody around to ask you will have to take the time and examine yourself the old server settings in as much detail as possible. Whatever people tell you here will be mostly guesswork since we don't know your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As m000 commented, there are a bunch of reasons.  I would say the most common reason for needing multiple interfaces on a webserver is if you are hosting multiple SSL sites.  Historically, those absolutely had to be on different IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are using the IPs. For example, each IP can be used for different domain if the web server is serving two domains.